# Why is the following equality true: $e^{\lambda I t} = e^{\lambda t}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I have seen in the following youtube tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnnbJ6VJfOQ that $$e^{\lambda I t} = e^{\lambda t}$$

Why is that true?

Comment: Because $\lambda I=\lambda$?

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not true. What's true is $e^{\lambda It}=e^{\lambda t}I$.

Comment: This isn't true. The left side is a matrix. The right side is a scalar. It's $e^{\lambda It}=e^{\lambda}I$; the video just skips the step of noting that writing $I$ is unnecessary for the particular calculation he's carrying out.

Comment: $e^{\lambda I t} = e^{\lambda t}$ is true as an **operator equivalence** when both sides are considered to act on vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be $$e^{\lambda t I }=e^{\lambda t}I\ \ \ (1)$$?

(where $e^{\lambda t I }$ is a matrix exponential, in particular a matrix, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $e^{\lambda t} I$ is the identity matrix $I$ multiplied by the scalar $e^{\lambda t}$)

It follows almost directly from Taylor expansion of the matrix exponential that $e^{tI}=e^t I$.

$$e^{tI} = tI+\frac{t^2}{2}I + \frac{t^3}{3!}I + \dots =\ (t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\dots)I=e^t I$$

Formula (1) then follows by a change of variables $s=\lambda t$.